# Termination of the current state of the function with any other user actions outside of the running function (FSM) Aiogram

Tags: python, state, telegram-bot, fsm, aiogram

The problem occurs when another function is called from the button. When a certain state is triggered in which the bot reproduces the menu, if the user presses any other button on the playback keyboard, the state ends, but does not issue a new action requested by the user. In order for this action to work, the user must once again click on the button that he wants to activate. I hope the problem is clear. (**At the moment of the running state, in order for the user to open another menu, it must be called twice. the first time - completes the state, the second time - starts a new function. Need an idea how to solve this problem**)

```py
poster = ['any url', 'any url', 'any url']
name = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot,
                storage=storage)


class Test(StatesGroup):
    Q1 = State()


next_button = InlineKeyboardButton(text='next', callback_data='next')
back_button = InlineKeyboardButton(text='back', callback_data='back')

nbtn_callback = [next_button.callback_data, back_button.callback_data]

nbtn = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=True)
nbtn_next = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=True)
nbtn_next.add(next_button)
nbtn.row(back_button, next_button)

a = KeyboardButton('cancel')
b = KeyboardButton('Photo')

menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
menu.row(a, b)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_bot(message: types.Message):
    txt = "Hello!\n"
    await message.answer(txt, reply_markup=menu)
    await message.delete()


@dp.message_handler(text='Photo', state=None)
async def photo(message: types.Message):
    reply_markup = nbtn_next
    await Test.Q1.set()
    await bot.send_photo(
        message.chat.id,
        photo=poster[0],
        reply_markup=reply_markup,
        caption=name[0],
    )


@dp.message_handler(text='cancel', state=None)
async def cancel(message: types.Message):
    ph = "any url photo"
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                         photo=ph)


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Test.Q1)
async def photo_update(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if callback.data == "next":
        i = await state.get_data()
        i = i.get("answer")

        if i is None:
            i = 1
        else:
            i += 1
        file_path = poster[i]
        await state.update_data(
            {"answer": poster.index(file_path)}
        )
        file = InputMedia(media=file_path, caption=name[i])
        await callback.message.edit_media(file, reply_markup=nbtn)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT, state=Test.Q1)
async def stop_state(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
```

As you can see this part of the code is for the completion of the state, but due to this design, a new action is required for it to work

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT, state=Test.Q1)
async def stop_state(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your function(stop_state) at the top of file with handlers.

My function(cancel_operation) looks like this and it works.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['cancel'], state="*")
async def cancel_operation(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
"""Cancel current operation"""

try:
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer(
        text=message_cancel_action,
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
except Exception as error:
    logger.error(f"[ERROR] {error}")
```